# Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation IONIC 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

This works correctly when run as development, but when you run the command to production the following error:

Working:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

Not working:

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --release
```

**ERROR:**

```
    [03:34:41]  typescript error
                Unexpected module 'TranslateModule in C:/Users/tm_ma/Doc/PROJECT/node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/core.d.ts' declared by the module 'EmentaPageModule in
                C:/Users/tm_ma/Doc/PROJECT/src/pages/ementa/ementa.module.ts'. Please add a
                @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
  [03:34:41]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
  [03:34:41]  Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
    Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
```

**EMENTA MODULE:**

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular'; 
import { EmentaPage } from './ementa'; import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';


@NgModule({  
   declarations: [
    EmentaPage,
    TranslateModule
       ],   imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(EmentaPage),
    TranslateModule
       ], }) export class EmentaPageModule {}
```

**App Module:**

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })

  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
   ...
  ],
  providers: [

  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Version:**

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",   
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",   
"@angular/animations": "5.2.11",    
"@angular/common": "5.2.11",    
"@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",   
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",    
"@angular/core": "5.2.11",    
"@angular/forms": "5.2.11",   
"@angular/http": "5.2.11",
```

Comment: `TranslateModule` shouldnt be in declarations array. Try after removing from there

Comment: @SurajRao thanks for answering
,i removed from declrations array , know give me this -> [14:20:09]  typescript error
            The pipe 'translate' could not be found (" <ion-header class="menu-nav"> <ion-navbar> <ion-title>{{[ERROR
            ->]'INFOALUNO.headerMsg' | translate}}</ion-title> </ion-navbar> </ion-header> ")

Answer (score 0):

Angular5 should be use core 8.x - 9.x and loader 1.x - 2.x
Angular4.3 should be use core 7.x or less and loader 1.x - 2.x

details there https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

My app used ionic4 (angular6) and the ngx-translate is ok for me (core 10.x and loader 3.x)